# Windows phone silverlight UI update from control handler

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, silverlight, windows-phone

Let's consider the following method that simply update a stack panel:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = new TextBlock();
        t.Text = "TEXT1";

        var t2 = new TextBlock();
        t2.Text = "TEXT2";

        dummyStack.Children.Add(t);

        // This can be any synchronous work 
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        dummyStack.Children.Add(t2);
    }
```

Off course the interface is updated after ~5 seconds, which means when the method finishes its execution. My question is, is there any way to force UI update when the stack panel it's first modified with the first text block, then after 5 seconds next UI update etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you task.Delay instead of sleep.  This will allow the ui to update while the code is waiting

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = new TextBlock();
        t.Text = "TEXT1";

```
    var t2 = new TextBlock();
    t2.Text = "TEXT2";

    dummyStack.Children.Add(t);

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    dummyStack.Children.Add(t2);
}
```

Comment: Actually the `Thread.Sleep(5000);` was just an example there. There could be any synchronous work done.

Comment: In that case make the work async await Task.Run(()=> { etc...});

Comment: Unfortunately that part can't be changed, so I wonder if there is any other way to do it..

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to add the controls

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code into two sections, run the first section immediately (synchronously), and setup the second section to run (asynchronously) after the silverlight framework code had run and updated the visible UI with the changes from your first section.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //synchronous section
    var t = new TextBlock();
    t.Text = "TEXT1";
    dummyStack.Children.Add(t);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        //asynchronous section
        ()=>{
            var t2 = new TextBlock();
            t2.Text = "TEXT2";
            // ... heavy calculations
            dummyStack.Children.Add(t2);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task.Delay that will cause switching of context to UI for a moment. That could be your solution.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = new TextBlock();
    t.Text = "TEXT1";

    var t2 = new TextBlock();
    t2.Text = "TEXT2";

    dummyStack.Children.Add(t);

    await Task.Delay(100);

    // This can be any synchronous work 
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    dummyStack.Children.Add(t2);
}
```